# SourceTree Keeps Asking for Credentials for GitHub

Tags: github, credentials, sourcetree

Until 2 days ago, I dont even remember if I ever saw these prompts but since 2 days, I get them every 2-3 minutes.  I am on Windows 10, SourceTree 1.9.6.1, using GitHub repository I have been using before.  So, nothing has changed other than that I believe I updated SourceTree couple of days ago (I might be wrong with this but I believe I did it.).

Last 2 days, I get these 2 prompts every 2-3 minutes.

First this one:

[image]

then right after I enter my credentials in the form above, I get same from SourceTree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this issue as well. I've not investigated it thoroughly, but entering the credentials, then restarting the app eventually worked for me.

The issue resurfaced every time I upgraded ST or made other large changes to the configuration, and went away by the same method.

I've also asked a few admins at the local university, who all told me that there is no reliable fix and to just live with it and hope it does away.